# Test ad works, but normal doesn't

Tags: unity-game-engine, ads

I made a game and added ads that turn on with a separate button. Ads from unity ads. In the unity project, test ads work and turn on when needed. I found out that real advertising does not work when I posted it on Google Play and the testers had no advertising. Test mode disabled in: code, unity dashboard and services[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvOqs.png)

Comment: Please don’t share screenshots of your code. As a new contributor please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Make sure test mode is set to false in the Unity inspector as well. Not just in the code, because it is a serialise field.

Comment: test mode turned off wherever possible. Yes, and if advertising was included, at least test would be played. And I don't have any

Comment: When you try to watch an ad what does it show?

Comment: Does it say something like “test ad”? Or is it just a blank screen?

Comment: Does it say something like “test ad”? Or is it just a blank screen? ,  
Ariel Developer

Comment: What are you saying? I was asking you a question

Comment: when I watch test ads in the project, test ads turn on (I'm sorry I didn't send it)

Comment: Please include a screenshot of when you watch a test ad.